# 'no implicit conversion of Symbol into Integer' happened when create new record

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I can't figure out why 'no implicit conversion of Symbol into Integer' error arises.

Parameters is here

```
Started POST "/articles/confirm" for ::1 at 2017-03-22 14:59:43 +0900
Processing by ArticlesController#confirm as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"M6I30basDNNPrU+TVBE1VuF2XtKZSdZvU+bFQms2PjNqpbl6YwWlg1BxN6+DF7viZV3g==", "article"=>{"article_histories_attributes"=>{"0"=>{"title"=>"cdscsa", "content"=>"<p>cdcdscsa</p>"}}, "status"=>"work_in_progress", "user_id"=>"11", "update_user_id"=>"11", "current_version"=>"1", "articles_article_series_attributes"=>{"article_id"=>"0", "series_id"=>"1", "num"=>"10"}, "publish_at(1i)"=>"", "publish_at(2i)"=>"", "publish_at(3i)"=>"", "publish_at(4i)"=>"", "publish_at(5i)"=>"", "publish_until(1i)"=>"", "publish_until(2i)"=>"", "publish_until(3i)"=>"", "publish_until(4i)"=>"", "publish_until(5i)"=>""}, "commit"=>"comfirm"}
```

My code in controller is below.

```
def confirm
   @article = Article.new(article_params)
```

Here is just what happened.

And my Strong parameter defines like this.

```
private
  def article_params
    params.require(:article).permit(:id, :current_version , :publish_version, :file, :status, :user_id , :update_user_id, :publish_at, :publish_until, category_list: [], tag_list: [] , article_histories_attributes:[:id, :article_id, :version, :title, :content, :comment], article_images_attributes:[:id, :article_id], articles_article_series_attributes:[:article_id, :series_id, :num])
  end
```

I use three models which form has_many-through relations.

Article.rb

```
class Article < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :articles_article_series
  has_many :article_series, through: :articles_article_series
```

Articles_article_series.rb

```
class ArticlesArticleSeries < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :article_series, foreign_key: "series_id"
  belongs_to :article

  self.table_name = "articles_article_series"
```

Article_series.rb

```
class ArticleSeries < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :articles_article_series
  has_many :articles, through: :articles_article_series

  self.table_name = "article_series"
```

Please tell me how to fix this problem. Thanks in advance.

Comment: post your full error log.

Comment: Protip - don't write your strong parameters in a single line of code. Its very hard to read.

Comment: Thanks guys. I finally found out what's the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I changed my view code like this.

```
= hidden_field_tag "article[articles_article_series_attributes][article_id]", @article.articles_article_series.try(:article_id)
```

to this.

```
= hidden_field_tag "article[articles_article_series_attributes][0][article_id]", @article.articles_article_series.first.try(:article_id)
```

Then it solved. Sorry for bothering.